# Tried to import a javascript template into a rails app might have broken something in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to import a static javascript template into a basic rails app, so that I can then build more rails functionality with it (particularly with the backend).
Here is a window into some possibly related directories / files...

### /app/assets/stylesheets/

- application.css
- base.css
- blue.css
- bootstrap-responsive.css
- bootstrap-responsive.min.css
- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap.css.erb
- bootstrap.css.scss
- bootstrap.min.css
- bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
- docs.css.less
- fontawesome.css.erb
- glyphicons.css
- sprites.css.erb

### /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
/* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, 
* which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, 
* lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can 
* be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file 
* and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a 
* new file per style scope.
*
*= require formtastic-bootstrap
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

### /app/assets/fonts:

- glyphicons readme.txt
- glyphicons-regular.otf
- glyphicons-regular.svg
- glyphicons-regular.ttf
- glyphicons-regular.woff
- glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot
- glyphiconshalflings-regular.otf
- glyphiconshalflings-regular.svg
- glyphiconshalflings-regular.ttf

I would be extremely grateful for any help at all, thank you so much!

=== UPDATE =====

As @m_x suggested, I needed to have my manifest file (i.e. application.css in the app --> assets --> stylesheets directory) match the order that files were referenced in the original template (in the index.html  tag). Here is the new version:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *  add after glyph <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap.min.css
 *= require bootstrap-responsive.min.css
 *= require glyphicons.css
 *= require google-fonts.css
 *= require base.css
 *= require blue.css
 */
```

=======

The above code was based on the index.html file from the template, the important part of which is as follows:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/blue.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note that I manually created a file to contain the css found in the 4th URL listed above (I named this css file "google-fonts.css"), because I wasn't sure how to reference a URL...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Just a bit of advice : first, it is recommended that you provide informations directly on your post, not as links - links break after some time, so people with similar problems looking for answers cannot use your question. Moreover, your question is unclear : we do not know what exactly your problem is. Is suspect that it is "my scripts and styles are broken since i tried to use the asset pipeline", but a little clarity helps everybody.

Comment: Now, I think your problem comes from your manifest files : you use `require_tree`that loads all files _in alphabetical order_. Please edit your question to be more specific and informative and I (or someone else) will be glad to point you out appropriate solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable advice @m_x, I really appreciate it and will make the changes you suggested asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple files with the same name but different extensions. I'm not sure that `erb`, `scss`, `less` files won't overwrite the standard `css` during compilation, so this *may* be one cause of your issue.

Other than that, the problem most certainly stems from the fact that `require_tree` includes files *in the order it finds them on the filesystem*. This means that, in your case, `bootstrap-responsive.css` may get included **before** `bootstrap.css` (depends on your filesystem). As you know, the order in which files are included is very important for both stylesheets and scripts.

There are two main solutions to force the order of inclusion :

1. instead of `require_tree`, use `require <filename>` as described in [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) and include *each file manually*, in any order you want (i.e. the order you included them in the head before using the asset pipeline). To ease management and tidy your folder, you can split your assets into different folders ; if you create a manifest named `index` in a folder, using `require <folder_name>` will include this manifest. That's what i usually do.
2. Some people prefer prefixing each file with a number, e.g. `01_bootstrap.css`, `02_bootstrap-responsive.css`, etc. I never used this approach but AFAIK it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you @m_x! This worked! I will now update my question to reflect the specific changes I made...

Comment: If the answer provided solved your issue to your content, please be sure to choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: indeed. just click on "accept answer" below the score, on the left. As to your update, just two remarks: 1) updating your questioin is unnessecary if you accept an answer, 2) for external content (such as libs delivered by a CDN), do not include them in manifest files. Just stick to the habitual script tag. This way, you will leverage the benefits of using a CDN (for instance, your user's browser may have already cached the font you requested on googleapi from another site, so you don't have to serve them)